# manipular combobox sem id via vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Tipo de Documento



    Selecione
    Selecao 1
    Selecao 2
    Selecao 3

esse seria o codigo se tivesse o id:

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainForm:j_id218").SetAttribute("value", "Selecao 1")
End Sub

Como seria o cdigo para poder funcionar?